# I want to make one button for each letter in the alphabet, in a GUI, without having to have 100+ lines just for the buttons

Tags: python

I am trying to learn PyQt5 and I was wondering if it is possible to have a condensed form of what I have shown below.
The below Already works but i was hoping that maybe there is a condensed version. All the buttons will end up doing the same thing, which is filling in the word for the hangman game I am making.

Now i have tried a for loop that looks like this. where every thing else in the program is the same but now I inserted a for loop thinking maybe that would fix the length problem.

```
def initUI(self):
    self.setGeometry(700, 250, 700, 700)
    self.setWindowTitle("Hang-Man")
    btn=[]
    for i in range(27):
        btn.append(i)
        j=i*25
        btn[i].move(20,int(j))
        btn[i] = QPushButton(chr(i), self)
        btn[i].clicked.connect(self.close)
```

Here is the code that actually works as intended though. This goes all the way to z with the increments shown here.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.show()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(700, 250, 700, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle("Hang-Man")

        btn1 = QPushButton('A', self)
        btn1.move(20, 25)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.close)

        btn2 = QPushButton('B', self)
        btn2.move(20, 50)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.close)

        btn3 = QPushButton('C', self)
        btn3.move(20, 75)
        btn3.clicked.connect(self.close)

        ... #this continues all the way to Z

def run():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())`

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop:

```
buttons = {}

def make_buttons(text, number):  # text is a list
    for x in range(1, number+1):
        buttons[f'btn{x}'] = QPushButton(text[x-1], self)
        buttons[f'btn{x}'].move(20, 25*x)
        buttons[f'btn{x}'].clicked.connect(self.close)
```

Comment: Yes, it would .

Comment: Do I need to call upon it again with in that block or would that fall into the run block that i have created. (sorry I am trying I am just not good)

Comment: When you say text is a list where is that text called upon? Also, when `buttons[f'btn{x}']` also shows the f as part of the string

Comment: pass in a list of the letters a-z as text. f-strings don’t include the f

Comment: when i do that it shoots back an error saying that app is not indexable

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. The only thing i’m indexing is a list

Comment: thats what I thought but it still throws back that error

Comment: are you saying insert a list for the text value? because i did that and it said what I said earlier and then. If you are saying that can you show me how you would go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a horizontal layout for your window:

```
self.createHorizontalLayout()

windowLayout = QVBoxLayout()
windowLayout.addWidget(self.horizontalGroupBox)
```

You can get more information on the [PyQT5 website](https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-horizontal-layout/)